# How to update table values using if else condition in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am adding permission values using this function in My Controller.

```
public function addPermission(Request $request, $id,  Permission $permission)
    {
         $this->validate($request, [
            'status'   => 'required'


        ]);

        $permission = new Permission;

        $permission->status = $request->input('status');
        $permission->project_id       = $id;
        $permission->collaborator_id =  $request->input('cid');
        $permission->save();
        return redirect()->back()->with('info','Permission has been added to your Collaborator successfully');
}
```

How can I write update code here using if else condition when I change permission value?

Comment: Can you please explain why you want to set condition before update?

Comment: actually I need add some values and when I need update values in this same function.

Comment: It's not clear what your condition is. If *what*?

Comment: you know that in My above function I can add permission values to table. I need update function when I want update that value. I need update this value withing this **addPermission** functions.

Comment: can you specify which value or data you really wanted to updated? your question seems unclear

Comment: I need update status values